# How to intercept out-of-proc desktop STA COM to STA COM communication or reference counting decrementing?

Tags: winapi, com, ipc

My example:
PowerPoint start Excel when insert embedded workbook.
I continue to work with PowerPoint. Excel stays as hidden process.
When I close PowerPoint it says to Excel to close itself (Excel closed later then PowerPoint).
When I kill PowerPoint, Excel becomes zombie.
My add-in is loaded into Excel process.

What message(I read that COM STA objects communicate through windows messaging) I should intercept to be notified about such event? What hook should I use? Is there any mean to be notified about count of reference to COM object changes?

**UPDATE**

My question seems was ambiguous. I am not trying to handle case when I kill PowerPoint. It just for evidence that PowerPoint send some message to Excel when closed normally. I am trying to intercept this message for a good reason.

**UPDATE2**

I cannot use API - because API fails. I am trying to solve [Creating class in new thread in new app domain and providing it with Office COM object in embedded mode leads to zombie process](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/officegeneral/thread/79ac9e40-e8d0-4b71-9fb8-eb14a78c866a)

Comment: There is no good mechanism in out-of-proc COM to deal with unexpected process termination.  Hard crashes are caught and reported back to the client with the RPC_E_SERVERFAULT error code.  The server stays running.  If you shoot it in the head yourself then it's your job to clean up the mess.

Comment: "I am trying to intercept this message for a good reason." There is no good reason to do this. What are you ***actually trying to do***?

Comment: I added UPDATE2 describing my issue.

Comment: I have had a look at your issue and I suspect that the issue is that you never release the Excel application object. You need to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject when you are done with an object - remember GC is not deterministic, and for some reason Interop objects don't support using/IDisposable, so you can't even use that.

Comment: Also why do you want to use the Excel Application object on a different thread? What are you trying to do that makes you think that is a solution?

Comment: I cannot release using Marshal.ReleaseComObject because Excel does not calls shutdown/disconnection callbacks and I do not know when to release. I in my case I even do not reference it anywhere in my code.

Comment: Marshaling Excel in different thread to child domain is just sample. But I checked that even code like "marshalledObject is Application" leads to zombie when called in different thread in child domain.

Comment: And all code works when Excel working in full mode.

Comment: @asd.and.Rizzo, Expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

**None.** COM on a local server does use windows messages but it uses private messages which are an implementation detail. All it really does is post messages to a hidden window meaning "you have new COM events in your apartment". The hidden window passes this to the COM library which uses (I believe) shared memory to communicate with other processes, and does the rest of the work such as finding out what the event is (call, call return etc).

In other words, there is no specific message to say "excel go away", and even if there was you couldn't rely on it becaues it is an implementation detail which can change.

- When you close the PowerPoint document containing the embedded spreadsheet, PowerPoint will call IUnknown::Release() on all the objects it holds. Excel keeps an internal track of outstanding objects, and will close itself when they all go away.

If you have an add-in in the excel process, and want to know when excel closes, use the addin api to find out.

Depending on the type of Add-In there are different APIs for this. The COM add-ins have events you can register for. But that is a different question: "how can my Excel add-in get notification that an invisible Excel instance is closing".

**Added Solution to actual problem/question not asked**

@asd.and.Rizzo, this is occurring because you hare holding on to the objects created by Excel. This means that Excel thinks it cannot exit because someone is using the objects. Excel is correct because that somone is your add-in.

This sort of lifetime issue is typical when creating any Office or Excel add-in and is not unique to .Net add-ins.

You are wanting to solve the problem by cheating Excel's reference count. But it is in your hands: The reference count is only up because you are holding objects! If you release them the count will go down to zero with no cheating.

**Solution**

The best solution is to avoid sinking events and avoid holding on to any object. Depending on what your add-in is doing this may not be possible.

If you cannot, you must sink the document close events. In each, check how many documents are open. When the count reaches zero you should remove your event handlers, call Marshall.ReleaseComObject on every object you have ever held, and unload your add-in. Excel will then exit.

But please note: You ***must*** call Marshall.ReleaseComObject on **every** object you ever hold. If you don't, Excel will never exit. This **should** occur if you unload the AppDomain.

Comment: Is there any way to intercept IUnknown::Release() called in relation to Excel in Excel add-in?

Comment: @asd.and.Rizzo, You are asking the best way to cut off your toes to fit into a shoe. ***Don't do that***. You need a different shoe. Why don't you tell us what problem you are actually trying to solve? Some of us have written Excel add-ins and know a bit of COM so may be able to help.

Comment: I deleted my previous post at this forum stayed without answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you kill 'PowerPoint' there will be no reference count changes in Excel. That is why it is not being unloaded.

I believe you may simply post WM_QUIT message to the main window of the Excel process. You may find it using "Spy++.exe" which is a tool bundled with Visual Studio. Also, it is possible, that you may acquire a class factory for some object in Excel and invoke the 'LockServer' method with fLock = FALSE. This will decrease the reference count of Excel server.

But take this as a hack, since an add-in should not influence the behavior of the host application.

Comment: I think it could be cool to "release" Excel prematurely using some native API. I will try IClassFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I found next (from interpreting COM interfaces as pure C structs + function and Direct X hacks). Works but does not fix problem for some reason. My be should do the same for Workbooks, Worksheets...

Declare:

```
typedef HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterfacePtr(  REFIID, void **);
typedef ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRefPtr( );
typedef ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE ReleasePtr( );

 typedef ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCountPtr( UINT *) ;
 typedef  ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoPtr     ( UINT, LCID, ITypeInfo **) ;
  typedef ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNamesPtr   ( REFIID, LPOLESTR *, 
                                        UINT, LCID, DISPID *) ;
  typedef ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE InvokePtr          ( DISPID, REFIID, 
                                        LCID, WORD, DISPPARAMS *,
                                        VARIANT *, EXCEPINFO *, UINT *) ;

typedef struct {
       // IUnknown functions
    QueryInterfacePtr  * QueryInterface;
    AddRefPtr          * AddRef;
    ReleasePtr         * Release;
       // IDispatch functions
 GetTypeInfoCountPtr* GetTypeInfoCount;
 GetTypeInfoPtr* GetTypeInfo;
 GetIDsOfNamesPtr* GetIDsOfNames;
 InvokePtr*  Invoke;


} IDispatchInterceptor;



typedef ULONG __stdcall releasePTR(IDispatch *self);
typedef ULONG __stdcall addrefPTR(IDispatch *self);
```

Next I have done for Excel:

`static IDispatch * application = NULL;
static releasePTR* realRelease = NULL;
static addrefPTR* realAddRef = NULL;
static ULONG wasAdd = 0;
static ULONG oldCount = 0;`

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterfaceNativeOutOfProcSrv(REFIID riid, void **ppv){
    return application->QueryInterface(riid,ppv);
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRefNativeOutOfProcSrv(){
return application->AddRef();
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE ReleaseNativeOutOfProcSrv(){
return application->Release();
}

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCountSrv( UINT * count) {
      return application->GetTypeInfoCount(count);
  }
   ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoSrv    ( UINT n, LCID id, ITypeInfo ** inf) {
       return application->GetTypeInfo(n,id,inf);
   }
   ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNamesSrv   ( REFIID a, LPOLESTR * b,  UINT c, LCID d, DISPID * e) {
            return application->GetIDsOfNames(a,b,c,d,e);
   }
   ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE InvokeSrv          ( DISPID a, REFIID b,  LCID c, WORD d, DISPPARAMS * e,  VARIANT * i, EXCEPINFO * j, UINT *k) {
           return application->Invoke(a,b,c,d,e,i,j,k);
   }

static IDispatchInterceptor interceptor = 
{QueryInterfaceNativeOutOfProcSrv,AddRefNativeOutOfProcSrv,ReleaseNativeOutOfProcSrv,
GetTypeInfoCountSrv,GetTypeInfoSrv,GetIDsOfNamesSrv,InvokeSrv
};

ULONG __stdcall release(IDispatch *self)
{

```
ULONG c = realRelease(self);
    Log->logWrite("release %d",c);

    if (  c == 1) 
    {
        if (instance != NULL) 
       {

          instance->OnBeginShutdown(NULL);
          Log->logWrite("OnBeginShutdown %d",c);
          instance->OnEmbeddedDisconnection();
           Log->logWrite("OnEmbeddedDisconnection %d",c);
           instance = NULL;
        }
    }
//if (c == 2) {
//  c = realRelease(self);
//    c = realRelease(self);
//}

return c;
```

}

ULONG __stdcall addref(IDispatch *self)
{
    ULONG c = oldCount;
    if (wasAdd == 0)
    {
        c = realAddRef(self);
        oldCount = c;
        wasAdd++;
    }
    else if (wasAdd == 1)
    {
            Log->logWrite("ADDREF FAKE %d",c);
        wasAdd++;
    }
    else if (wasAdd == 2)
    {
            Log->logWrite("ADDREF FAKE %d",c);
        wasAdd++;
    }
    else
    {
        c = realAddRef(self);
    }
    Log->logWrite("ADDREF %d",c);
    return c;
}

void InterceptRelease(  IDispatch *obj){
    void* iunknown_vtable= (void*)*((unsigned int*)obj);
    void* idispatch_vtable = (void*)(((unsigned int)iunknown_vtable)+8);
    unsigned int* v1 = (unsigned int*)idispatch_vtable;
    realRelease =  (releasePTR*)*v1;
    DWORD old;
    VirtualProtect(v1,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&old);

```
*v1 = (unsigned int) release;

//while(obj->Release() > 0){};
```

}

void InterceptAddRef(  IDispatch *obj){
    void* iunknown_vtable= (void*)*((unsigned int*)obj);
    void* idispatch_vtable = (void*)(((unsigned int)iunknown_vtable)+4);
    unsigned int* v1 = (unsigned int*)idispatch_vtable;
    realAddRef =  (addrefPTR*)*v1;
    DWORD old;
    VirtualProtect(v1,4,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&old);
    *v1 = (unsigned int) addref;
}

Apply:

```
 IDispatch * app  = Application;
 InterceptRelease(app);
 InterceptAddRef(app);
```